# Mostrar texto en un Select ya cargado

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Muy buenas tardes amigos.

Que gusto saludarlos, espero que se encuentren de maravilla. Tengo el siguiente código. Se carga un select, se guarda la informacion de acuerdo con el usuario y su seleccion y luego se activa para que sea actualizada, pero al necesitar actualizarla no coloca la informacion traida del servidor en el Select lo que con los inputs lo hace perfecto

````
            <input class="btn btn-primary ml-3" id="masMulti" type="button" value="Adicionar" style="width: 150px;">
            <label class="labelcenter ml-3 mr-3">Tamaño Lote</label>
            <input type="text" id="loteTotal" class="form-control" style="width: 100px;" readonly="">
            <input type="text" id="transitoMulti" hidden="">
          </div>
            <div class="insertarRefMulti mb-3 mt-3">
              <select class="form-control" name="MultiReferencia" id="cmbMultiReferencia1" onchange="cargarReferenciaM();">
                <option disabled="" selected="">Multipresentacion</option>
                <option value="0">SHAMPOO NUTRICION - (450 ml)</option>
                <option value="1">SHAMPOO NUTRICION - (1.000 ml)</option>
                <option value="2">SHAMPOO NUTRICION - (80 ml)</option>
             </select>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cantidadMulti1" name="cantidadMulti" placeholder="Unidades" onblur="CalculoloteMulti(this.value);">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tamanoloteMulti1" name="tamanoloteMulti" readonly="" placeholder="Lote">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="densidadMulti1" name="densidadMulti" placeholder="Densidad" hidden="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="presentacionMulti1" name="presentacionMulti" placeholder="Presentación" hidden="">
            <button class="btn btn-warning eliminarMulti" type="button">X</button></div>        
        </div>
      <div class="inputcalculoTotal mb-3 mr-5" style="display: flex; justify-content:flex-end">  
        <label class="labelcenter ml-3 mr-3" style="padding-right: 10px;">Total</label>
        <input id="sumaMulti" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 28%;" readonly="" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="guardar_Multi();">Aceptar</button>
      </div>
>  ```

``` $(document).on('click', '.link-editarMulti', function(e){
    editar=true;
    limpiarMultipresentacion();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url : 'php/multi.php',
        data: {operacion : "6", id :data.id_batch},

        success: function(response){
            
            var info = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(info);
            console.log(info[0].nombre_referencia);

                $("#masMulti").click();
                var referencia = info[0].nombre_referencia;
               
                $('#cmbMultiReferencia1 option').text(referencia);
                $('#cantidadMulti1').val(info[0].cantidad);
                $('#tamanoloteMulti1').val(info[0].tamano);
                $('#densidadMulti1').val(info[0].densidad);
                $('#presentacionMulti1').val(info[0].presentacion);
                CalculoloteMulti();
 
        }

    })

    $('#Modal_Multipresentacion').modal('show');
}) ```
````

Comment: Saludos. Realiza los cambios necesarios para recibir (o si ya lo tienes úsalo) el dato 
 `value` que corresponde al `option` seleccionado y no su **descripción**; si por algún motivo te conviene la descripción mira en **Selected Text** ( en el siguiente link https://techbrij.com/jquery-operations-on-dropdownlist-combobox ) el que tiene `filter`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Roberto, sin embargo al utilizar el filter, no entiendo porque no muestra la selección que deseo `$('#cmbMultiReferencia1 option')
                    .filter(function() { 
                        console.log($(this).text());
                        return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == referencia; })
                    .attr('selected',true);`

Comment: Saludos. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-selected-option-in-dropdownlist-by-the-text-not-value al final de la página esta como debe ser; así mismo un ejemplo http://jsfiddle.net/qYRr7/ una de las cosas es que distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas; es decir no es lo mismo `Hola` que `hola` por tanto no lo encontraria. Así mismo, tu `select` tiene `onchange` asignado; mira no este igual afectando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. La seleccion la hago trayendo los datos desde la base de datos para eliminar el erro de no encontrarla, como me dices. el onchange en la seleccion lo hago porque cada vez que se cambia la seleccion llena los inputs de acuerdo con los datos traidos de la BD.  sabes si hay alguna cosa que deba hacer si es un modal?